# Loop through array and append to different HTML elements

Tags: javascript

I have 3 HTML columns and an array with 3 objects within it. I'm trying to loop through the array and append the value within the array to each of the HTML column.  So the first object in the array to the first column ,second object to the second column. Which type of loop would be best for this scenario?

```js
var shortenedCast = fullCast.slice(0, 3);
var arrayLength = shortenedCast.length; //3
var columns = document.getElementsByClassName("panel-item");
var characterP = document.getElementsByClassName("character");

for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  console.log(shortenedCast[i].character);
  //John wick
  //Viggo Tarasov
  //Iosef Tarasov
  characterP.textContent = shortenedCast[i].character;
}

console.log(shortenedCast);
```

```html
<div class="column small-4">
  <div class="panel-item">
    <p class="character"></p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="column small-4">
  <div class="panel-item">
    <p class="character"></p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="column small-4">
  <div class="panel-item">
    <p class="character"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Comment: You've already got it, it's just that `getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection`, so you can do `characterP[i].textContent ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Heretic Monkey that worked

For people viewing the solution was to add [i] in front of the characterP

```
var fullCast = credits.cast;


var shortenedCast = fullCast.slice(0,3);
var arrayLength = shortenedCast.length;
var columns = document.getElementsByClassName("panel-item");
var characterP = document.getElementsByClassName("character");

    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        console.log(shortenedCast[i].character);  
        characterP[i].textContent = shortenedCast[i].character;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking maybe a more dynamic approach without having to add new Divs every time you increase the array.

```html
arr = ['John wick', 'Viggo Tarasov', 'Iosef Tarasov'];

function createColumns(arr) {
  let colItems = [];

  arr.map(item => {
    colItems.push(`
      <div class="column small-4">
        <div class="panel-item">
          <p class="character">${item}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      `);
  });

  return colItems;
}

document.getElementById('someDivID').innerHTML = createColumns(arr).join('');
```